# Creating a new dictionary variable in a class python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, initialization

If I create a class like below:

```
class Foo(object): 
     foo = {'useful_info': 'useful_info'}  
     def __init__(self, foo, bar): 
         self.foo['foo'] = foo 
         self.bar = bar
```

and I create an instances of it and print it's attributes as:

```
Foo1 = Foo('foo1', 'bar1')
print(Foo1.foo)
print(Foo1.bar)
```

I get the output:

```
Foo1 = Foo('foo1', 'bar1')
print(Foo1.foo)
print(Foo1.bar)
```

However, now if I create a new instance named Foo2 and print the attributes of both Foo1 and Foo2 as:

```
Foo2 = Foo('foo2', 'bar2')

print("Foo2.foo: ", Foo2.foo) 
print("Foo2.bar: ", Foo2.bar) 
print("Foo1.foo: ", Foo1.foo) 
print("Foo1.bar: ", Foo1.bar)
```

I get the output:

```
Foo2.foo:  {'foo': 'foo2'}
Foo2.bar:  bar2
Foo1.foo:  {'foo': 'foo2'}
Foo1.bar:  bar1
```

The string attributes `bar` have been set as I expect, but the dictionary `foo` has been updated for both instances of Foo.

I can get round this by declaring the dict `foo` in the **init** magic method as:

```
class Foo(object): 
     def __init__(self, foo, bar): 
         self.foo = {'useful_info': 'useful_info'} 
         self.foo['foo'] = foo 
         self.bar = bar
```

but now the dictionary `foo` containing 'useful_info' isn't accessible until the **init** function is called i.e. if I use the line: `Foo.foo` I get an AttributeError.

Is there any way to create a new dictionary containing some 'useful_infomation' so that the useful info is accessible before the class is initialised and every new instance of a class has a different instance of this dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) of the dictionary within `__init__` so each instance has a deep copy of the dictionary, instead of sharing the same `foo` dictionary object.

```
import copy

class Foo(object): 
    foo = {'useful_info': 'useful_info'}  
    def __init__(self, bar): 
        self.foo = copy.deepcopy(Foo.foo)
        self.bar = bar
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I think the self.foo['foo']... line should be replaced with self.foo = copy.deepcopy(self.foo)

Comment: But, why do they share the same `foo` object ?

Comment: The original question had the argument 'foo' being set as a value under the key 'foo' of the dict foo. I understand this probably wasn't the best naming system!

To answer this while keeping the functionality of the original question the dict foo would have to be re-created in the __init__ and in that new dict the key foo should be set to the argument foo. 

Though I agree this pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just combine both:

```
class Foo:
    foo = {'useful_info': 'useful_info'}
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = {'useful_info': 'useful_info'}
        self.foo['foo'] = foo
        self.bar = bar
```

Comment: Wouldn't `foo['useful_info']` be overwritten by the call of `__init()__` ? If it was used and modified before that call, wouldn't it be an issue ?

Comment: @AniMir the *class variable* would not be modified, because an instance variable with the same name is created the line above it... `self.foo = {'useful_info': 'useful_info'}`